# How to change temperature in Today's Summary part from F to C in Notification Center

Tags: macos, settings, notifications

I'm using Mac OS (El Capitan) and in Notification center, Today's Summary part it shows weather information. **I want to change from F to C here**. My weather widget is already in C and working fine.[image: Today's Summary]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open `System Preferences`
2. Click `Language & Region`
3. Select `Advanced`
4. Change `Measurement units` to `Metric`

Add-on note: You may have to do this a couple of times or cycle through the options to make it stick.

Comment: Thanks. Its a small things but matters :)